# How can I set the starting indentation offset in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I want the indentation to start only from second level of code.
So,

[image: before]

should become

[image: after]

automatically. I tried to tweak the settings but I can't get it working. Is there a way or a plugin to do that ?

(P.S. Yeah, I can do it manually but then if I select `Reformat Code` (which I use a lot) the code will get back to place like in the first screenshot).

Answer (score 4):

Adjust the Code Style for HTML and add the script tag to the list of elements for which children will not be indented. (See attached picture)

[image: Editor->Code Style->HTML->Do not indent children of:]

Comment: I'll be glad to supply a bigger image ;)
You're welcome, though.